# Create Google Cloud Storage Upload URLs for PHP7.2

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, php-7.2

I feel like I'm missing something here, but on Google App Engine using PHP 5.5 in the standard environment I can create upload URLs very easily for my users to upload files to without wasting time in PHP, like so:

```
<?php
use google/appengine/api/cloud_storage/CloudStorageTools;

?><form action="<?php echo CloudStorageTools::createUploadUrl('my/upload/handler.php'); ?>" method="post">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Enormously simplified of course (as that URL would only last 60 seconds).

However this API doesn't appear to be available to app engines running PHP 7.2, which I really need to use, and I can't seem to find an alternate API for obtaining upload URLs; have these really been discontinued?

There were other really useful features like `getImageURL()` for getting thumbnails and such as well. Of course a lot of the documentation still points to the above method for handling user uploads to an app engine site!

So how do I create and utilise upload URLs in the newer API?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can create and utilise upload URLs with [PHP 7.2 Google Client Library](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/tree/master/appengine/php72/storage) for Cloud Storage.

You can directly put the handler in the action attribute of the form without calling the API.

Note that in this sample you put the name of the bucket in which the files will be uploaded as an environment variable in the **app.yaml** file:

```
runtime: php72
env_variables:
  GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET: <your_bucket_name>
```

**index.php**:

```
<?php

namespace Google\Cloud\Samples\AppEngine\Storage;

use Google\Auth\Credentials\GCECredentials;

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

$bucketName = getenv('GOOGLE_STORAGE_BUCKET');
$projectId = getenv('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT');
$defaultBucketName = sprintf('%s.appspot.com', $projectId);

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']){

       case '/user/upload':
          upload_file($bucketName);
          exit;
    }
    header('Location: /');
    exit;
}
?>

<html>
  <form action="/user/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
            Files to upload: <br>
           <input type="file" name="uploaded_files" size="40">
           <input type="submit" value="Send">
  </form>
</html>
```

**Handler function**:

```
function upload_file($bucketName)
{
    $fileName = $_FILES['uploaded_files']['name'];
    $tempName = $_FILES['uploaded_files']['tmp_name'];
    move_uploaded_file($tempName, "gs://${bucketName}/${fileName}.txt");
    sprintf('Your file "%s" has been uploaded.', $fileName);
}
```

**composer.json**:

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/cloud-storage": "^1.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^5",
        "google/cloud-tools": "^0.6"
    }
}
```

I suggest you clone the sample from Github and try it yourself.

Comment: Somehow missed the notification for this answer; but this to me looks like the file is being uploaded to an app engine service and then moved into Google Cloud Storage. Google upload URLs allowed files to be uploaded by a user directly into a bucket using a securely generated URL, with a callback to the service then allowing the service to log details of the file once complete.

Comment: To clarify; upload URLs went 1) generate direct Google Storage URL and display form, 2) receive callback a if file was uploaded, i.e- no file is sent to app engine itself. This looks like a) display form b) receive file c) move into cloud storage, which means the entire file must be received by app engine.

Comment: In that case I believe that in PHP 7.2 you can [create a signed url in the handler](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.68.0/storage/storageobject?method=signedUploadUrl) and then use the [SignedUrlUploader method](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-php/#/docs/google-cloud/v0.68.0/core/upload/signedurluploader) with the signed URL that you created to begin the upload of the file/s.